# Membership test for iterators

Tags: python, iterator

Can somebody explain me the behaviour of membership test in the last 3 lines of my code bellow, why is it False?
Why is the membership test  different for iterators and iterables?

```
c = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]

print(3 in c)   # True
print(3 in c)   # True

d = iter(c)
print(2 in d)   # True
print(4 in d)   # True
print(4 in d)   # False  ???
print(6 in d)   # False  ???
print(10 in d)   # False  ???
```

Comment: After you try to lookup 4 for the second time, the iterator is empty since it iterated through all values looking for 4.  Try casting it to a list after that lookup and see what you get, you should get `[]`

Answer (score 4):

Iterators are consumed when used. I'll explain on your example:

```
>>> c = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
>>> d = iter(c)
>>> print(list(d))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
>>> print(list(d))
[]
```

You can think of the iterator `d` as of a pointer to the first item in the list. Once you read its value, it points to the second item. When it reaches the end, there it points to an empty list.

See also this:

```
>>> c = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
>>> d = iter(c)
>>> print(next(d))
1
>>> print(next(d))
2
>>> print(list(d))
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

Checking whether something is in it also consumes its contents:

```
>>> c = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
>>> d = iter(c)
>>> 4 in d
True
>>> print(list(d))
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

Comment: So, it is also calling  __next__  when looking for 4 and that consumes the iterator. Understandable, but for the membership test and the in operator, shouldn't it be implemented differently - to not consume the iterator while just searching the value in it?

Comment: @MarkoSavic An iterator implements only one thing: `next`. There is no other way to get anything from it. The question here is whether you should be using an iterator at all...

Answer (score 0):

The question looks quite stale, but recently, I was doing some experiment with my own iterator class that gave me some insights into the inner workings of the membership check. Here is the code which illustrates what is happening. I hope it is helpful.

```py
import logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s|%(levelname)s: %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%H:%M:%S, %d-%b-%Y', level=logging.INFO)
class Iterator:
    """Customise the Iterator with logging messages."""
    def __init__(self, max_value:int=20):
        """Initialise with a default state and a maximum value"""
        self.max_value:int=max_value
        self.value:int=-1
    def __iter__(self):
        """Part of the usual iterator protocol."""
        return self
    def __next__(self)->int:
        """Part of the usual iterator protocol."""
        logging.info(msg=f'Next was called with {self.value}')
        self.value+=1
        if self.value>self.max_value:raise StopIteration
        return self.value
sample_iterator=Iterator()        
3 in sample_iterator # Gives True
3 in sample_iterator # Gives False
```

The log output for first check

```
11:12:19, 19-May-2023|INFO: Next was called with -1
11:12:19, 19-May-2023|INFO: Next was called with 0
11:12:19, 19-May-2023|INFO: Next was called with 1
11:12:19, 19-May-2023|INFO: Next was called with 2
```

and the output for next check

```
11:12:31, 19-May-2023|INFO: Next was called with 3
11:12:31, 19-May-2023|INFO: Next was called with 4
11:12:31, 19-May-2023|INFO: Next was called with 5
11:12:31, 19-May-2023|INFO: Next was called with 6
11:12:31, 19-May-2023|INFO: Next was called with 7
11:12:31, 19-May-2023|INFO: Next was called with 8
11:12:31, 19-May-2023|INFO: Next was called with 9
11:12:31, 19-May-2023|INFO: Next was called with 10
11:12:31, 19-May-2023|INFO: Next was called with 11
11:12:31, 19-May-2023|INFO: Next was called with 12
11:12:31, 19-May-2023|INFO: Next was called with 13
11:12:31, 19-May-2023|INFO: Next was called with 14
11:12:31, 19-May-2023|INFO: Next was called with 15
11:12:31, 19-May-2023|INFO: Next was called with 16
11:12:31, 19-May-2023|INFO: Next was called with 17
11:12:31, 19-May-2023|INFO: Next was called with 18
11:12:31, 19-May-2023|INFO: Next was called with 19
11:12:31, 19-May-2023|INFO: Next was called with 20
```

This is my conclusion. When you ask for membership check of an element, the iterator starts calculating the `next` from its present state, until it gets

- The element it is searching, when it returns `True`
- StopIteration, when it returns `False`
- Continue until the end of time until one of the above happens

More concretely,

```py
val:bool=elem in sample_iterator
```

is equivalent to

```py
val:bool
while True:
    try:
        current=next(sample_iterator)
    except StopIteration:
        val=False
        break
    if elem==current:
        val=True
        break
```

Bottom-line, the membership test is an *intrusive* test on an iterator. Do not perform this test on an iterator, or any class where you know the check itself will alter the inner state.

Answer (score -1):

Because iterator has a state - in your case a pointer to the current element.

The difference between two sequential checks

```
print(4 in d)   # True
print(4 in d)   # False  ???
```

is the state of the iterator. After first check iterator's pointer set to next element after 4.

Comment: How is this an answer?